# Refactoring mutate to update or set - Angular 16 to Angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript, refactoring, angular16, angular17

I have this code

```
this.items.mutate(products => this.sourceData.getData().forEach(item => products.push(item)));
```

updating the library from Angular 16 to Angular 17 I need to remove 'mutate' using 'update' or 'set', but I don't know how to do it.
I should change `products.push(item)`-> `[...products, item]` but I don't know how to do it with the `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v17 signals enforce immutability, therefor you need to return a new instance of your array. Using a spread operator is a good option:

```
this.items.update(products => {
 return [...products, ...this.sourceData.getData()]
})
```

Comment: Not working @Matthieu it says Argument of type '(products: Product[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Product[]) => Product[]'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.

Comment: Please see my edit, It was missing a `return`